# How to add a custom view to JSQMessagesViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

How can i add a custom view on the top of collection view? 
I  want to design a custom view using Xcode user interface 
I have added my view in storyBoard view controller but the collection view covers it
so I add a custom view in viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self addViewOnTop];
    }
}
-(void)addViewOnTop {

    UIView *selectableView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 60, self.view.bounds.size.width, 40)];
    selectableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    UILabel *randomViewLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10, 100, 16)];
    randomViewLabel.text = @"RandomView";
    [selectableView addSubview:randomViewLabel];
    [self.view addSubview:selectableView];
}
```

this code runs successfully but how can I load a view using Xcode interface builder or load a .XIB file

now I do this

```
@implementation chatViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
    self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(70, 0, 0, 0);
    self.collectionView.dataSource = self;
    self.collectionView.delegate= self;
    messages = [NSMutableArray array];
    [self addMessages];
    self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.incomingAvatarViewSize = CGSizeZero;
    self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.outgoingAvatarViewSize = CGSizeZero;
    self.topContentAdditionalInset = 70.0f;
    UITapGestureRecognizer* tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleCollectionTapRecognizer:)];
    [self.collectionView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
    self.collectionView.semanticContentAttribute = UISemanticContentAttributeForceLeftToRight;
    [self addViewOnTop];
}
-(void)addViewOnTop {
    commentsheader *test = [[commentsheader alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 70)];
    [self.view addSubview:test];

}
```

but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding the real problem that you are having is that your `customView` is covering the `collectionView` instead of modifying the storyboard just adjust the inset of the collection view.

Add an UIEdgeInset to let you view your messages under the new view Call this in the viewDidLoad()

```
self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 40, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

Comment: ok at first its not my question but now it is my question but no matter 
i have edit the question @daniel leonard

Comment: What is your question now?

Answer (score 0):

You should try out `currentView.bringSubview(toFront: <UIView instance>)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the navigation bar hides the view.
But bringing it to the front didn't fix the problem
but doing this fixed it:
in viewDidLoad

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```